# java udp send from specific IP address

Tags: java, networking, udp, nio

I have a server with many IP addresses, and a UDP socket bound to 0.0.0.0 so I can receive UDP from any of them.  How can I specify the source IP address to use in the UDP packets I am sending?  My current implementation is using NIO so maybe using the DatagramChannel to perform the sending is the problem.

Comment: Why? IP will route them correctly via the correct interface as determined by the IP routing tables, and put that interface's IP address into the outgoing datagram. NB You don't have. 'Java code bound to 0.0.0.0', you have a UDP socket bound to 0.0.0.0.

Comment: The system I am sending the packets to will use the source IP as information, so I need to choose a specific source IP  from my local IPs.

Comment: That is a *non sequitur* for the reason I already gave.

Comment: @user207421 This capability is absolutely needed.  For example, for load testing SNMP, where a single linux server is given ~5000 IP addresses (10.0.0.1-10.0.19.254), and binds on 0.0.0.0.  When it receives an SNMP request directed at, for example, 10.0.2.20, the response that it sends should originate from 10.0.2.20 as the source address in the packet, even though the server is bound to 0.0.0.0 -- because, as noted below, many NMS depend on the source address in the response (packet) matching the dest of the request target (10.0.2.20).

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on a clean solution and just use a bound DatagramSocket per IP address on server that can be used to send UDP with the specific source IP for the outbound packets.

Answer (score 0):

The following program demonstrates that your requirement is imaginary. It shows that a datagram packet originated at a `DatagramSocket` bound to 0.0.0.0 is delivered with a source-address of 127.0.0.1.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    DatagramSocket  ds1 = new DatagramSocket(0);
    int port = ds1.getLocalPort();
    System.out.println(ds1.getLocalAddress());
    DatagramSocket  ds2 = new DatagramSocket();
    byte[] bytes = {0x01};
    SocketAddress sa = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", port);
    DatagramPacket  dp = new DatagramPacket(bytes, 0, bytes.length, sa);
    ds2.send(dp);
    ds1.receive(dp);
    ds2.send(dp);
    ds2.receive(dp);
    System.out.println(dp.getAddress());
}
```

Comment: Of course, if I did not care what source address was placed into the UDP packet.  However my question was to select the source address.

Comment: But you didn't state why you think you need this. You don't.

Comment: When you receive a UDP packet, you have access to both source and destination IP/ports.  The server I am communicating with (SNMP NMS) is using the source address of the inbound packets .  I have access to both of these fields when I receive UDPm but when sending on a socket bound to 0.0.0.0, I was hoping to be able to hint/pick the source address (from multiple IPs on server) which to use when sending.